# How to fix GitLFS Authorization error via SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, centos, gitlab, git-lfs

After updating to GitLFS v2.9.1 and GitLab 12.5+ on our tool server the git lfs commands on our staging and production server has stopped working out of nowhere.

The strange thing is that it still works just fine on our development machines on window 10.

Have someone an idea how to fix this problem or how to narrow it down?

Thank you very much!

```
LIV server.test gitresources # sudo git reset --hard origin/ptr
Downloading x/remoteResources/icons/x/x.png (8.7 KB)
Error downloading object: x/remoteResources/icons/x/x.png (873dd61): Smudge error: Error downloading x/remoteResources/icons/x/x.png (873dd61a4de1b23d4a8a86cff92b718ea76d89548d9df1b62e8652c93bbfb3cb): batch response: Authentication required: Authorization error: https://gitlab.x.com/x/x/app.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that you have proper access to the repository
Errors logged to /root/*/gitresources/.git/lfs/logs/20191203T134636.060635499.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed 2
error: external filter git-lfs smudge -- %f failed
```

---

```
16:57:09.952506 git.c:557               trace: exec: 'git-lfs' 'pull'
16:57:09.952585 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'git-lfs' 'pull'
16:57:09.963827 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'version'
16:57:09.969638 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'config' '-l'
16:57:09.972510 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=cat' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=cat' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
16:57:09.975174 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=cat' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=cat' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' 'HEAD' '--symbolic-full-name' 'HEAD'
16:57:09.980910 trace git-lfs: tq: running as batched queue, batch size of 100
16:57:09.983528 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting ".gitattributes"
16:57:09.983571 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "lfs-test.iml"
16:57:09.983587 trace git-lfs: filepathfilter: accepting "testimage.jpg"
16:57:09.985367 trace git-lfs: fetch testimage.jpg [4d1a66693a39c26b90f1f9d94a5194b0e21696448811a3d06c58af48135accf4]
16:57:09.985535 trace git-lfs: tq: sending batch of size 1
16:57:09.985793 trace git-lfs: run_command: ssh -- git@gitlab.x.com git-lfs-authenticate x/lfs-test.git download
16:57:10.498126 trace git-lfs: api: batch 1 files
16:57:10.498765 trace git-lfs: HTTP: POST https://gitlab.x.com/x/lfs-test.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
> POST /x/lfs-test.git/info/lfs/objects/batch HTTP/1.1
> Host: gitlab.x.com
> Accept: application/vnd.git-lfs+json; charset=utf-8
> Authorization: Basic     *
> Content-Length: 204
> Content-Type: application/vnd.git-lfs+json; charset=utf-8
> User-Agent: git-lfs/2.9.1 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.13.1; git 7b479cc8)
>
{"operation":"download","objects":[{"oid":"4d1a66693a39c26b90f1f9d94a5194b0e21696448811a3d06c58af48135accf4","size":282810}],"transfers":["lfs-standalone-file","basic"],"ref":{"name":"refs/heads/master"}}16:57:10.789562 trace git-lfs: HTTP: 401


< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Content-Length: 26
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Date: Wed, 04 Dec 2019 15:57:10 GMT
< Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< Server: nginx
< Set-Cookie: experimentation_subject_id=ImM2MDI4ZWNiLWU3ZGQtNDZlMy1iMmNhLTVmYTlhNWI4ZTNkMCI%3D--6842ebb28f88d6209a31d6eec652a825e85d6664; domain=.x.com; path=/; expires=Sun, 04 Dec 2039 15:57:10 -0000; secure; HttpOnly
< Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="GitLab"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
< X-Request-Id: fOZLAsyMCw9
< X-Runtime: 0.184977
< X-Ua-Compatible: IE=edge
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
<
16:57:10.789961 trace git-lfs: api error: Authentication required: Authorization error: https://gitlab.x.com/x/lfs-test.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that you have proper access to the repository
batch response: Authentication required: Authorization error: https://gitlab.x.com/x/lfs-test.git/info/lfs/objects/batch
Check that you have proper access to the repository
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://gitlab.x.com/x/lfs-test.git/info/lfs'
```

- I have replaced some parts of the urls with a `x` since it is company property

GitLFS v2.9.1
GitLab 12.5.3
OS: CentOS

Comment: Using a gitlab deploy key instead a user key bypass this issue but the root cause is still unclear.

Comment: Bug Report: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/38119

Answer (score 0):

The linked bug report didn't help, but maybe someone else searches for this so I may leave here what was the issue for me: proxy environment variables. We have a gitlab server running in our intranet, and in my `.bashrc` I have the `http_proxy` etc. variables set to be able to connect to the internet. Unsetting these variables, and re-trying the checkout with LFS did the trick.